# What's this gibberish at the end of my JWT token?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm using the PHP League's OAuth2 Client library to authenticate my PHP application against Azure Active Directory. Authenticating works, but when I try to get the logged in user's info, I get the dreaded "Access Token missing or malformed":

```
{  
   "odata.error":{  
      "code":"Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
      "message":{  
         "lang":"en",
         "value":"Access Token missing or malformed."
      },
      "values":null
   }
}
```

Inspecting the token I'm using, I see a bunch of gibberish at the end, which I feel might be the issue, as everything else SEEMS to be intact:

```
{  
   "typ":"JWT",
   "alg":"RS256",
   "x5t":"xxxxxxx",
   "kid":"xxxxxxx"
}{  
   "aud":"https://graph.windows.net/",
   "iss":"https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/",
   "iat":1432806357,
   "nbf":1432806357,
   "exp":1432810257,
   "ver":"1.0",
   "tid":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
   "oid":"yyyyyyyyyyy",
   "upn":"user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
   "puid":"yyyyyyyyyyyy",
   "sub":"xyxyxyxyxyxyxyx",
   "given_name":"First",
   "family_name":"Last",
   "name":"user",
   "amr":[  
      "pwd"
   ],
   "unique_name":"user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
   "appid":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "appidacr":"1",
   "scp":"Directory.Read user_impersonation UserProfile.Read",
   "acr":"1"
}�x·���mk���2_w}Qc��t�0n� ��!���w.@|~�)/�#SW��V��ؽ����8>f�ޒ�x��_����s��[������7�ٍ�=TpD��qI'R\���_*�  3�0P�M?���є�B�>ѣ   �)?+Zxd晩�p_Z�������;�Bg���5v�s�Q`~ٛ1*2��)Q}ٙ�sS���vթ���݉���V@�-9�m��be��x+�|    �Ë��b
```

Any idea where this gibberish is coming from? And is this the issue preventing me from retrieving user data?

Comment: _"Any idea where this gibberish is coming from?"_ - It's the signature bytes. JWTs in [JWS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41) form come in three parts - header, claimset, and signature

Comment: How are you obtaining the access token? What flow? How are you attempting to get the signed in user's data? (What call, against which API? AAD Graph API, presumably?)

Answer (score 1):

The gibberish is the token HMAC, which you can use to verify if the token is valid.